# I want to convert a csv file which has data in rows and columns to lists in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
    from assign1_utilities import get_column, replace_column, truncate_string

    import csv

    inputfile = csv.reader(open('athlete_data.csv','r'))


    for row in inputfile:

        print(row)
```

is what I have used but how do i have one list for every row of data?

Comment: Add Sample input and Output Expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row you define is already a python list.
I print the type below. Please also remember to close the file you open you are leaking a file handle in this code. I suggest you use with statement instead.

```
import csv

inputfile = csv.reader(open('test.csv','r'))

for row in inputfile:
    print type( row)
```

for test.csv file:

```
item,value,dir
1,15,saher
2,30,hello
5,16,good
```

it prints this:

```
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
```

So for example, this code adds each row to your list of lists if you wish to do so.

```
import csv

inputfile = csv.reader(open('test.csv','r'))

list_of_lists = []

for row in inputfile:
    list_of_lists.append(row)

    column_values = row.split(',')

    # do whatever you want with the values in columns
    # e.g to check length of 3rd column is 
    # if len( column_values[2] > 3 ) : do something ...
```

Comment: so the code i used, or yours as well outputs many lists. so how can i interact with one specific column of the data? for example:
if i want to make sure that the third item (that is the words "saher","hello","good") in your list do not exceed two characters, how do i do that?

Comment: you create a list that holds these lists and after you are done reading, you interact with any list you want.

Comment: Your question asks about row not column. CSV is comma-seperated so you can use split  ` columns = row.split(',') ` which will return a list of each column value. Then columns[2] will be the value in third column

Comment: thanks i think i am starting to get it, it would be of great help if you could tell me the code you would use to check if the maximum character of the third item in the lists is 3?

Comment: column[2] is the third value. To get the length of a string you use `len(column[2])` and you do whatever with it.

Comment: @MujibulIslamDipto sure anytime. Please accept the answer / upvote. Much appreciated.